# Does the name of an HTTP status code matter

Tags: http, http-status-codes

Say I'm sending some HTTP status code in PHP, do I actually need to do

```
header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
```

or is it enough to

```
header('HTTP/1.1 301 FooBar');
```

I once did this in a quick and dirty reverse proxy, where I could only get the code, not the message, from a CURL response and sent it back with `FooBar` as message. This appeared to work fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Via the [spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html#sec6.1.1):

> The individual values of the numeric status codes defined for
>   HTTP/1.1, and an example set of corresponding Reason-Phrase's, are
>   presented below. The reason phrases listed here are only
>   recommendations -- they MAY be replaced by local equivalents without
>   affecting the protocol.